# How to disable auto new line in verilog mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, verilog, mode

Each time I want to post my question it always show the problem “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted”, why this happens. I can only post my question as code. Sorry for the inconvenience.

```html
I am fairly new to emacs.
Whenever I type a semicolon( ; ) in my verilog code, it puts a
"new line" character automatically. How to disable this
automatic entry of new-line character?

I searched this question on google. Somebody answered 

"Hi Ravi,
        I am not sure which "mode file" you are using. If you are using the
one from Mac (Verisity) then have a llok at the file "verilog-mode.el"
You will see
;       verilog-auto-newline             t
;       verilog-auto-indent-on-newline   t
(defcustom verilog-auto-newline t
"t" means true, change it to "nil" and restart Emacs.
Another way to do through GUI is
On the menu bar you normally see a "special" pull down menu (if Verilog mode
is loaded) named "Verilog".
1.> Click on the Pull Down Menu Verilog
2.> Click on "Custmoize Verilog Mode..." (should be last but one option in
this menu)
3.> Then "open" the INDENT group
4.> Look for an option named "auto new line" and set this to nil.
5.> Save options..
Hope this helps.
Good Luck,
Srini

"

I modified my verilog-mode.el in ~/elisp, but it did not work.
Auto new line still happens. 
And I can't find a verilog mode menu bar on emacs menu bar. 
Can somebody tell me how to show the verilog mode menu bar on my emacs? Many thanks.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add

```
(setq verilog-auto-newline nil)
```

in your `~/.emacs` file?

Comment: I find that I should open a .v file then I can see the verilog mode menu bar, I disabled the auto new line in that menu bar, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My .emacs has this:

```
(defun my-verilog-hook ()
   ;; the (setq verilog-auto-indent-on-newline nil) below wasn't
   ;; stopping the auto indentation, but this does:
   (define-key verilog-mode-map "\r" nil))
(add-hook 'verilog-mode-hook 'my-verilog-hook)
```

And that seems to have fixed it for me.

Comment: I find that I should open a .v file then I can see the verilog mode menu bar, I disabled the auto new line in that menu bar, thank you anyway.